# some HTML links not working on server

Tags: html, hosting

I've just uploaded my HTML/CSS website to my new hosting. Locally all links are working fine. But on server all links to the images and some links to .html documents that are deeper in folders don't work.

For example from index.html: 
the link to kategorii/oblekainakit.html is working.

```
<a href="kategorii/oblekainakit.html"></a>
```

but the link:

```
<img class="port-img" src="kategorii/oblekainakit/oblekainakit.jpg">
```

is not working!

also when the .html document is two folders deeper the links to js/css are not working and i'm using "../../" for every link but with no results.

Can you please help me (the domain is www.bizniskatalog.mk).

Thanks

Comment: Use absolute paths. "http://www.bizniskatalog.mk/kategorii/oblekainakit/oblekainakit.jpg  <-- this is just an example, all I am really trying to tell you is use the website url in full.

Comment: @floor, have you tried to click this link?

Comment: Also just a quick look see... I edited one of your image paths and the image showed up. <img src="../../img/logo.svg" class="logow">

Comment: @ForceBru As I pointed out it is an example not a hard fix. I go on to say I am only trying to convey using the full web address

Comment: @floor, when you click on this link, it shows HTML (!!) instead of jpg. WTF??

Comment: @ForceBru yeah weird output but I guess the server is just cutting off the image part and routing to the next available thing.

Comment: Well clearly this person has some file locations all screwed up because what works for some images doesn't work for others. I recommend re-thinking the file structure and organizing all your assets (images) into 1 folder and only your html into 1 folder and all css into 1 folder and all js into 1 folder. Makes it a lot easier to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

When the files are uploaded it is important if the files are with CAPS or not. Locally it doesn't matter but when on server somehow it does.